# ADC Overrun with Multimode, Scan and timer-triggered configuration

Tags: stm32, adc, c, timer, dma

I'm using the STM32F446VE with 3 ADCs. I have a 50 kHz PWM running and want 2 of the ADCs to measure 2 Channels synchronized with the 50 kHz PWM.

To achive this I used the regular simultanuous dual mode, and triggered the master ADC with the Trigger 8 Timer Out event, which runs at 50 kHz (by now I assume this doesn't make sense, as I could just trigger both ADCs with the timer 8 and have synchronous measurement, as long as they have the same sampling time, but I'd like to understand what went wrong anyways). Both ADCs have Scan Conversion enabled.

Now, as soon as the total ADC Conversion takes too long, I get an ADC Overrun. This can be achieved by reducing the Sampling Time, Resolution, Delay, or clock Prescaler. I get the same behaviour when I raise the Timer 8 Frequency.

What I find very odd is, that the overrun does not accur, when I make the ADC Conversion ver slow, for example by raising the Sampling Time to 480 Cycles, or raise the Prescaler to 8. Shouldn't I get an overrun exactly then, because the Conversion is slower than 50 kHz and therefore gets retriggered, before it is done??

I have added the code which does not work. As I've said, if I change for example the ADC Clock Prescaler to 8, it seems to work just fine.

Tim.c:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : TIM.c
  * Description        : This file provides code for the configuration
  *                      of the TIM instances.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "tim.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim8;

/* TIM8 init function */
void MX_TIM8_Init(void)
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  htim8.Instance = TIM8;
  htim8.Init.Prescaler = 1800-1;
  htim8.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim8.Init.Period = 2-1;
  htim8.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim8.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim8.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim8, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim8, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

void HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* tim_baseHandle)
{

  if(tim_baseHandle->Instance==TIM8)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM8_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM8_MspInit 0 */
    /* TIM8 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM8_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM8_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM8_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void HAL_TIM_Base_MspDeInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* tim_baseHandle)
{

  if(tim_baseHandle->Instance==TIM8)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM8_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM8_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM8_CLK_DISABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM8_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM8_MspDeInit 1 */
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

adc.c:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : ADC.c
  * Description        : This file provides code for the configuration
  *                      of the ADC instances.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "adc.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

/* ADC1 init function */
void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{
  ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode = {0};
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T8_TRGO;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 2;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the ADC multi-mode
  */
  multimode.Mode = ADC_DUALMODE_REGSIMULT;
  multimode.DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAACCESSMODE_2;
  multimode.TwoSamplingDelay = ADC_TWOSAMPLINGDELAY_5CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeConfigChannel(&hadc1, &multimode) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_12;
  sConfig.Rank = 2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
/* ADC2 init function */
void MX_ADC2_Init(void)
{
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc2.Instance = ADC2;
  hadc2.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc2.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc2.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc2.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc2.Init.NbrOfConversion = 2;
  hadc2.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_10;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc2, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_11;
  sConfig.Rank = 2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc2, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* adcHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 0 */
    /* ADC1 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC1_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration
    PC2     ------> ADC1_IN12
    PA6     ------> ADC1_IN6
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* ADC1 DMA Init */
    /* ADC1 Init */
    hdma_adc1.Instance = DMA2_Stream4;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_0;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_adc1.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(adcHandle,DMA_Handle,hdma_adc1);

    /* ADC1 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(ADC_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 1 */
  }
  else if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC2_MspInit 0 */
    /* ADC2 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC2_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**ADC2 GPIO Configuration
    PC0     ------> ADC2_IN10
    PC1     ------> ADC2_IN11
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* ADC2 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(ADC_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC2_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC2_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void HAL_ADC_MspDeInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* adcHandle)
{

  if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC1_CLK_DISABLE();

    /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration
    PC2     ------> ADC1_IN12
    PA6     ------> ADC1_IN6
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_2);

    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6);

    /* ADC1 DMA DeInit */
    HAL_DMA_DeInit(adcHandle->DMA_Handle);

    /* ADC1 interrupt Deinit */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1:ADC_IRQn disable */
    /**
    * Uncomment the line below to disable the "ADC_IRQn" interrupt
    * Be aware, disabling shared interrupt may affect other IPs
    */
    /* HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(ADC_IRQn); */
  /* USER CODE END ADC1:ADC_IRQn disable */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspDeInit 1 */
  }
  else if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC2_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC2_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC2_CLK_DISABLE();

    /**ADC2 GPIO Configuration
    PC0     ------> ADC2_IN10
    PC1     ------> ADC2_IN11
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1);

    /* ADC2 interrupt Deinit */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC2:ADC_IRQn disable */
    /**
    * Uncomment the line below to disable the "ADC_IRQn" interrupt
    * Be aware, disabling shared interrupt may affect other IPs
    */
    /* HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(ADC_IRQn); */
  /* USER CODE END ADC2:ADC_IRQn disable */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC2_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC2_MspDeInit 1 */
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

dma.c:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : dma.c
  * Description        : This file provides code for the configuration
  *                      of all the requested memory to memory DMA transfers.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "dma.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Configure DMA                                                              */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

/* USER CODE END 2 */

/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

main.c:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
 ******************************************************************************
 * @file           : main.c
 * @brief          : Main program body
 ******************************************************************************
 * @attention
 *
 * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
 * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
 *
 * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
 * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
 * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
 *
 ******************************************************************************
 */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "adc.h"
#include "dma.h"
#include "tim.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint16_t DMA_value[4];


/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM8_Init();
  MX_ADC2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim8);
  if (HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc2) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)DMA_value, 2) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 180;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Activate the Over-Drive mode
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```